# Calling a function property of a constructor inside another function property

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am getting an error when that Parent.one is not a function. Please explain why this happens in case of objects made from constructors and not when we define objects normally.

```
var Parent = function(){};
        Parent.prototype = {
            one: function(){
                console.log("bye");
            },
            two: function(){
                console.log("hello");
                Parent.one();
            }
        }
        var Child = new Parent();
        Child.two(); // logs "hello" and then throws an error that Child.one is not a function.
```

Comment: No, it should throw an error that `Parent.one()` is not a function.

Comment: `Parent` is a constructor, the variable name of `Child` is confusing. It's not a subclass, but an instance, and it should not be capitalised.

Comment: I've learned that this is how I should do it




var Parent = function(){};
        Parent.prototype = {
            one: function(){
                console.log("bye");
            },
            two: function(){
                console.log("hello");
                this.one();          // instead of Parent.one()
            }
        }
        var Child = new Parent();
        Child.two();

Comment: I learned it after I posted the question. So that someone doesn't waste time trying to explain. @Bergi please explain how this and Parent are different.

Comment: One is an instance, the other is the instance's constructor. They're just not the same. Attempting to call a method on them will have different outcomes.